# Where do I connect earth wire?

Tags: ac, ground, timer, wiring, grounding

I'm trying to use [this delay timer](http://www.ebay.in/itm/Universal-Programmable-Digital-cyclic-delay-relay-timer-switch-module-220V-ONOFF-/221450155697?pt=IN_Projectors_Accessories&hash=item338f7536b1) to control an exhaust fan. I have a 3 pin connection (with earthing wire) powering this fan and it works fine.

If I have to insert this delay timer module in between the fan and socket, what do I connect the earthing wire to ? Can I leave it connected to the fan's earthing wire directly (as it is now) and use the hot and neutral to connect to this module or should I be looking for another module supporting an earthing wire ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *must* connect any existing earth ground wires directly to the earth ground connection. Not doing so could be a violation of safety regulations and/or civil code.

While you're at it, put that timer in a proper box. As it is, it is very easy to come into contact with a hot connection (which is a violation of the above in its own right).

Comment: Thanks Ignacio.. So can I leave the two earth wires connected as it is and interface the hot, neutral wires to the timer ? (sorry if this is repetitive.. just want to be sure :) )

Comment: Yes. And make sure that you've identified the hot wire correctly, since that is the one that must be switched by the relay.